# How to reduce the width of a single div in grid system in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, bootstrap-5

```
<div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: right;" >
        mytext1
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: right;" >
        mytext2
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: right;" >
        mytext3
</div>
```

I need to reduce the size of only second `div` and I don't want to use `col-sm-1` since it's too small and don't want `col-sm-2` since it's too big. But I need something inbetween something like `col-sm-1.5` is there a way to resolve this.

Comment: You may define your own custom grid class with the wanted size or add a horizontal padding to your second div `px-2`

Comment: You might add another divs under the second div. For example, add 3 divs as children under the second div, give them `col-sm-4`, and write your text in the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your Custom class since bootstrap sm-1 and sm-2 corresponds to 8.33% and 16.66%  you can create a custom class like so:

```css
.col-sm-1-5 {
  flex: 0 0 12.5%;
  max-width: 12.5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: right;">
  col-sm-1
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1-5" style="text-align: right;">
  col-sm-1-5
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: right;">
  col-sm-2
</div>
```

Comment: This one actually worked..!!! but when I reduce the size of the window for mobile screen size the alignment of the custom class is messed up

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom class that calculates the width based off the 12 columns in the grid.

Here I am dividing `100%` by 12 to get the width of one column, and multiplying it by 1.5.

I have also added `padding: 0 15px` to the custom class to match Bootstraps default `15px` left and right padding for their `.col` classes.

The `media` query sets the column width back to 100% to match the behaviour of the bootstrap `col-sm` classes.

The screen widths for each breakpoint Bootstrap uses can be found in [their documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/).

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
}

.col-sm-1-half {
  width: calc((100% / 12) * 1.5);
  padding: 0 15px;
}

/* bootstrap sm breakpoint */
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px){
  .col-sm-1-half {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column col-sm-2">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="column col-sm-1-half">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="column col-sm-2">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one actually worked..!!! but when I reduce the size of the window for mobile screen size the alignment of the custom class is messed up as you can run and check the code the `mytext2` is aligned left but other 2 `divs` are aligned right

Comment: @Sanjay I have updated my answer to include a media query that sets the column width back to 100% to match the other bootstrap columns. The text is not left aligning, that is due to the padding in the element. I have reduced the text to demonstrate this.